# Toposes are monadic over categories

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory, monads

[Lambek showed that](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/BFb0066895) Toposes are Monadic over categories.  Can someone give the gist of this paper?  I am assuming that the category of toposes is the eilenberg moore category for some monad on the category of categories.  Can someone present this in detail?

Comment: Have you tried reading the paper? Or can you not get through the paywall?

Comment: Hi, I actually read this 10 years ago, back before I knew what a monad was (lol).  I can't get through the paywall.  There are no citations of this work either according to google scholar.  I find that shocking.

Comment: Well, I'm pretty sure it's not the only result of the kind. Lambek published a lot of papers around that time about free toposes, which I believe generally means free on a type theory, in some sense, and may be more important to logicians than the free topos on a category. One also has free toposes in a certain sense appearing in the classifying topos of a geometric theory. As to the paper itself-SciHub?

Comment: [Part of the paper is available from page 153 here](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=J2t6CwAAQBAJ&pg=PA153&lpg=PA153&dq=Toposes+are+monadic+over+categories&source=bl&ots=m6DKzNvGEQ&sig=ACfU3U0SYI0VwOdH37bnLNLJWMO7ebGTxw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwix65m4ltLgAhWnRhUIHYI1AigQ6AEwCHoECAMQAQ#v=onepage&q=Toposes%20are%20monadic%20over%20categories&f=false) if that's helpful.